# Why my android app is giving "your app keeps stopping" while connecting to mqtt broker

Tags: java, android-studio, client, mqtt, paho

I have written a code to connect my android app to mqtt server in android studio. I have added button "connect" after clicking it will show me connect message on screen. The moment I click the connect button, I get the message your android app keeps stopping. here is my code. I have uploaded necessary repositories and dependency and also permissions

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MqttAndroidClient client;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
        client =
                new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "tcp://mqtt.eclipse.org:1883",
                        clientId);


    }

    public void test(View V){
        try {
            IMqttToken token = client.connect();
            token.setActionCallback(new IMqttActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                    // We are connected
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"connected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"disconnected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        } catch (MqttException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Look into the logcat for more informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error Solved. There was problem in local broadcast manager file.